# Cannot specify a repository location

Tags: windows, svn, netbeans, version-control

I want to add a partly-made project into a local repository.

Firstly, I've opened cmd.exe and prompted:

> svnadmin create E:\repo\GC

Then, in the NetBeans project window:

[Project name]->Versioning->Import into Subversion Repository

A three step wizard popped up. At (1) I've specified the path as

> file:///E:\repo\GC

, but it gave me an non self-explanatory error:

> No information available for: file:///E:\repo\GC

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs require slashes, not backslashes. Your repository URL should be `file:///E:/repo/GC`. Run `svn info file:///E:/repo/GC` to make sure that it's properly set up before attempting to commit/import to it.